# PHP 5.4 filter_var() FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN bug? Or change from 5.3?

Tags: php, filter-var

I think I found a bug in PHP 5.4.23, but I suppose it is possible expected behavior as well.  I am expecting a filter_var call to return `null`, but it isn't.  Is this code correct, and is my assumption that this is a bug and not a recent change correct as well?

#### Test code

```
var_dump(filter_var(null, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE));
```

#### PHP 5.3.28 Results:

```
NULL
```

#### PHP 5.4.23 Results:

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: Confirmed: http://3v4l.org/PB6sp

Comment: @RocketHazmat That is a ridiculously awesome tool.  Thanks for that link!

Comment: It might be bug (or a fixed one): https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49510  Also in http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.8: `Bug #49510: Boolean validation fails with FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE with empty string or false.`

Comment: WEll, I can tell you it's [probably the patch for this one](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49510) (added in.... 5.4.8, [see this commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/a26390ef0c22be3637795d9b5ab1c445e1d3f847)); (Edit: damn, by searching for the commit, Rocket beat me to it ;) )

Comment: Probably Teporary bug - 5.4.7 => NULL already so it was fixed :)

Comment: It looks like a BC break to me. Let me look at it and will post an update later.

Answer (score -3):

Usually when a function returns `NULL` it succeded. `false` is returned when it failed (by convention).

Comment: `filter_var()` is a bit different.  Please see its documentation.